# Is OpenVX warpAffine accept a transposed matrix and how does it defined as row major?

Tags: c++, c, matrix, openvx

I am new to OpenVX, learning from the document that OpenVX uses a [row-major storage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.3/html/OpenVX_Specification_1_3.html#sec_host_memory). And the below matrix access example illustrate it, just like the ordinary row-major access pattern as we used in plain C code.

Then I go to the [vx_matrix](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.3/html/OpenVX_Specification_1_3.html#_vx_matrix) and [vxCreateMatrix](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.3/html/OpenVX_Specification_1_3.html#_vxcreatematrix) document page. The former has such statements:

> VX_MATRIX_ROWS - The M dimension of the matrix [REQ-1131]. Read-only [REQ-1132]. Use a vx_size parameter.

> VX_MATRIX_COLUMNS - The N dimension of the matrix [REQ-1133]. Read-only [REQ-1134]. Use a vx_size parameter.

While the latter said:

```
vx_matrix vxCreateMatrix(
    vx_context                                  c,
    vx_enum                                     data_type,
    vx_size                                     columns,
    vx_size                                     rows);
```

So according to my comprehension, in OpenVX world, when i said an MxN matrix, M refers to the row size and N refers to the column size. And the `vxCreateMatrix` declaration just follow what the [row-major storage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.3/html/OpenVX_Specification_1_3.html#sec_host_memory) said, parameter `column` first and then `row`.

However, it really confuses me when i reach [Warp Affine](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/specs/1.3/html/OpenVX_Specification_1_3.html#group_vision_function_warp_affine) page, it said:

> This kernel performs an affine transform with a 2x3 Matrix M with this method of pixel coordinate translation [REQ-0498]:

And the C declartion:

```c
// x0 = a x + b y + c;
// y0 = d x + e y + f;
vx_float32 mat[3][2] = {
    {a, d}, // 'x' coefficients
    {b, e}, // 'y' coefficients
    {c, f}, // 'offsets'
};
vx_matrix matrix = vxCreateMatrix(context, VX_TYPE_FLOAT32, 2, 3);
vxCopyMatrix(matrix, mat, VX_WRITE_ONLY, VX_MEMORY_TYPE_HOST);
```

If the M is a 2x3 matrix, according to the previous section, it should has 2 row and 3 column. Then why should it be declared as `mat[3][2]` and `createMatrix` accept `column=2` and `row=3` as argument? Is my comprehension totally wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good start and help for your implementation

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/sample-color-copy/top/color-copy-pipeline/color-copy-pipeline-the-scan-pre-process-openvx-graph.html